# Read values into dictionary if key exists in dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, key, return-value

How can I read values from a certain column of a dataframe if a key from from my dictionary exists in the dataframe.

```
d_shell = {
        'var' : 0,
        'var2' : 0,
        'var3' : 0,
        'var4' : 0,
        'var5' : 0
    }


for t in df['col']:
    new_dict = d_shell.fromkeys(['var', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5'])
    for key in new_dict.items():
        if key in df['col']:
            value = df['other_col']
        else:
            value = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List/dictionary comprehension is a good thing.

```
{k:df[df['col']==k]['other_col'].values for k,v in d_shell.items() if k in pd.unique(df['col']).tolist()}
```

You can find more information at [PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). It is one of these skills that not that easy to master if you are new to Python, but once you are familiar with it, it can be addictive.